# Implement Jquery Sortable on DataList Control

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am new to Jquery and I am trying to following this article [Jquery Example](http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/1715/how-to-implement-jquery-ui-sortable-in-datalist-control/) to setup this but I am unable to drag my Items around. Im not sure what i am doing wrong. My code is below. Thanks,

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

$(function () {
   $("#<%=dlProcessList.ClientID %> tbody").sortable({
       handle: ".handle",
       placeholder: 'ui-state-highlight',
       cursor: 'move',
       start: function (event, ui) {
           ui.placeholder.height(ui.helper.height());
       }
   }).disableSelection();
});        

<asp:DataList ID="dlList" runat="server" >
  <HeaderTemplate>
      <tbody>
  </HeaderTemplate>

  <ItemTemplate>
       // My Data to display
  </ItemTemplate>  

  <FooterTemplate>
      </tbody>
  </FooterTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Comment: are you receiving any javascript errors?

Comment: No when I look at in firebug (console window) I do not get any errors. I think i might be attaching to the wrong parent Item. $("#<%=dlProcessList.ClientID %> tbody").sortable({

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Add "//" to your script imports, like this:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Also remove all the sortable options and just use the defaults to see if you can get it working...

Change this:

```
$(function () {
   $("#<%=dlList.ClientID %> tbody").sortable({
       handle: ".handle",
       placeholder: 'ui-state-highlight',
       cursor: 'move',
       start: function (event, ui) {
           ui.placeholder.height(ui.helper.height());
       }
   }).disableSelection();
});
```

To this:

```
$(function () {
    $("#<%=dlList.ClientID %> tbody").sortable();
});
```

See if that gets it working.

Comment: I tried that just now and it does not fix it. i just get the text to show and will not sort.

Comment: Are you importing jQuery and jQuery UI Sortable scripts?

Comment: Yes, <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script> are in the head

Comment: I had nested tables inside each item so I needed to add add a `>` before `tbody` like so `$("#<%=dlList.ClientID %> > tbody").sortable();`

Answer (score 2):

Look, this may be your problem...

http://www.foliotek.com/devblog/make-table-rows-sortable-using-jquery-ui-sortable/

http://jsfiddle.net/bgrins/tzYbU/

Comment: Interesting links I will read through them, however I did get a resolution to my question. Thank you for the help anyhow!